# Bottom align clipped image in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Bottom align clipped image in Flutter

Hello!

I'm beginner in Flutter

The following image:

[image]

I clipped the lettuce image in half with ClipPath:

[image]

I'm trying to move it into bottom right to be similar to the following image:

[image]

I tried many times with my available experience with no luck

Here's the code:

```
class GroceryPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const GroceryPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [             
                const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                    color: const Color(0xFFE9F9F2),
                  ),
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      ClipPath(
                        clipper: HalfClip(),
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                          child: Image.asset(
                            '${kProductsImagesAsset}lettuce.png',
                            height: 150,
                            // width: 150,
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              'Get Up To',
                              style: kGreenTitleStyle.copyWith(
                                fontSize: 20.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              '%10 off',
                              style: kGreenTitleStyle.copyWith(
                                fontSize: 40.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
               
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me doing so?

Comment: which image is your expected output?

Comment: The current output is the second image. I want the lettuce image to be aligned to the bottom like in the third image

Comment: can you trying adding height on SizedBox(height:x, child: Stack?

Comment: Stack is a child of a container not sizedbox. I added height to the container and the output was: https://i.imgur.com/3bU30cL.jpg

Comment: increase the height, your image is small,

Comment: Increasing height made the Container bigger and the texts and image didn't move at all

Answer (score 1):

Use `Positioned` widget as Stack child.

```dart
Positioned(
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  child: Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      Text(
        'Get Up To',
        style: kGreenTitleStyle.copyWith(
          fontSize: 20.0,
        ),
      ),
      Text(
        '%10 off',
        style: kGreenTitleStyle.copyWith(
          fontSize: 40.0,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

More about using [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html)

```dart
class GroceryPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const GroceryPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                Container(
                  height: 300, //cardHeight
                  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                    color: const Color(0xFFE9F9F2),
                  ),

                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      Align(
                        child: Container(
                          height: 600, // full image height=  cardHeight*2
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                        // child: Image.asset(
                        //   '${kProductsImagesAsset}lettuce.png',
                        //   height: 150,
                        //   // width: 150,
                        //   fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        // ),
                      ),
                      Positioned(
                        top: 0,
                        left: 0,
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              'Get Up To',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              '%10 off',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 40.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This caused build crash with no changes in the screen

Comment: Can you `flutter clean` and rebuild the app?

Comment: The last code output: https://i.imgur.com/t2RTV7M.jpg

Comment: now the issue with full image? Use `Positioned( top:0. right:0,
                        child: Container(
                          height: 600, // full image height=  cardHeight*2
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),`

Comment: Also the same screen appeared

Comment: image height should be double  of Container height

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249482/discussion-between-ahmed-loutfy-and-yeasin-sheikh).

Comment: Hello Yeasin! let's continue if you have time

Comment: OK, join on the room